# Can't create a symbolic link with Textmate in Terminal. (mate: command not found)

Tags: terminal, textmate

I'm currently going through http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and it uses the command "mate" to access Textmate through the terminal. I have had Textmate on my Macbook Air (Lion OS) since I first bought it, but when I try to use a command like "mate .gitignore" the terminal gives me "mate: command not found".

I've looked through all other StackOverflow questions regarding this topic and have done the following:

- Attempted to create a symbolic link through the terminal with this code.

  ```
  $ sudo ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate /usr/bin
  ```

This code lets me enter my password and tells me the file exists, but still does not allow me to use the "mate" command.

- Accessed Textmate/Help/Terminal Usage and tried to create a link for `/usr/bin` only for it to say operation not permitted.
- Used `alias mate='open -a textmate'`. This works; however, I have to do it every time I open Terminal.

So, my question is can anyone tell me what is wrong? Love to figure this out!

Thank you!

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /Users/griffinlacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial/bin:/Users/griffinlacek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin:/Users/griffinlacek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin:/Users/griffinlacek/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, you should **not** add anything to `/usr/bin`. You should add it into `/usr/local/bin`. Further, getting the message "file already exists" from `ln` means that it did not create the link. Try this:

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate /usr/local/bin/mate
```

Depending on your current setup, this may have to be run with `sudo`. In general, if you don't know whether to run something with `sudo` or not, try without first and see if you get a permissions error, then use `sudo`.

Comment: Trying that I got "ln: /usr/local/bin/mate: No such file or directory". I then added sudo before it and it asked me for my password and returned the same thing.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin` exist? If not `mkdir /usr/local/bin` first.

Comment: It didn't but I just created it. (Had to use sudo) After I created it I could use your code and it created the link. I can now use the mate command. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I am also running into the same problem. I have tried this command : 
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/bin/mate /usr/local/bin/mate

But it says : ln: /usr/local/bin/mate: File exists

I have googled and also tried alias mate='open -a textmate'

Unfortunately, nothing is working for me. Could you please tell me the reason or what to do ?

Comment: @KeenLearner Make a backup of the file at `/usr/local/bin/mate`, then delete it and try linking again.

Comment: TextMate 2 appears to install the link, but there's no 'mate': $ which mate /usr/local/bin/mate/usr/local/bin/mate - then on trying: mate filename - line 2: exec: /Contents/Resources/mate: cannot execute: No such file or directory and SharedSupport just contains 'Bundles' - any ideas?

Comment: Please note: for TextMate2 you should use: `sudo ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate /usr/local/bin/mate

@Dave, please try that
`

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that there's no 'mate' in `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/`

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do it is from TextMate -> preferences -> Terminal and then check install
all the previous methods didn't work for me.

Comment: I'm guessing this may not have been an available feature when OP asked the question, but this has got to be the easiest way to install shell support.

Comment: This option is no longer under Preferences, but rather TextMate -> Help -> Terminal Usage...

Comment: I was having issues with the link and this worked for me.